# Dynamic lists and polymorphism

Tags: c++

I have a map of type < lookup_ID, vector< parentclass*>> each location in the map holds a vector of type child class. The idea behind this system is the ability to add a child into its associated map using an add(parentclass*) function and it would be able to find its associated vector of child type. I tried using templates and casting to get the vector to recognized the type of child input into the add function with no luck. I don't want to have to declare an add function for each child of parent, and no matter how I did it I had to declare a function for each type. I could take them out of the map but then again I'm left with the issue of calling each child for any function I want to implement. Is their no way to match types of polymorphic structures into dynamically allocated lists?`

```
    class Piece
    {
    public:
    pieceType ID;
    //...
    }

    class Infantry :
        public Piece
    {
    public:
    //...
    };

    class Artillery :

        public Piece
    {
    public:
     //...
     };

//...

//In some other classes somewhere

std::map<pieceType, std::vector<Piece*>*> units;
        units.emplace(Infantry_, new std::vector<Infantry*>);
        units.emplace(Artillery_, new std::vector<Artillery*>);

//...
template<typename T>

std::vector<T*> operator+(std::vector<T*> a, Piece * b) {

    a.push_back(static_cast<T*>(b));
    return a;

}

 add(Piece * piece){

units.at(piece->ID) = units.at(piece->ID) + piece;

}
```

Also I am aware that this code has some errors, it was more for an example of what i'm trying to say.

Comment: The given answers don't explicitly call this out, but you're looking for some form of what is known as Run-Time Type Introspection (RTTI).
Check the documentation for TypeId.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use virtual funciton to get the ID for each child class

```
class Piece
{
public:
  virtual PieceType ID() const = 0;
}

class Artillery
{
public:
  virtual PieceType ID() const override { /* return your ID for Artillery */ }
}

class Infantery
{
public:
  virtual PieceType ID() const override { /* return your ID for Infantery */ }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no relation between `std::vector<Piece*>` and either of `std::vector<Infantry*>` or `std::vector<Artillery*>`, so your map can only contain `std::vector<Piece*>`s.

This is for good reason. Imagine you have a `std::vector<Infantry*>`, and put a pointer to it into your `std::map<pieceType, std::vector<Piece*>*>`. You could then insert an `Artillery *` into that through the map.

Rather than exposing the `std::vector<Piece*>` directly, you could expose a (read only) view of it that casts to the particular subtype.

Using the ranges library

```
auto asInfantry = ranges::view::transform([](Piece * p){ return static_cast<Infantry *>(p); });
auto asArtillery = ranges::view::transform([](Piece * p){ return static_cast<Artillery *>(p); });

class PieceMap 
{
    std::map<pieceType, std::vector<Piece*>> units;

public:
    auto Infantry() { return units.at(Infantry_) | asInfantry; }
    auto Artillery() { return units.at(Artillery_) | asArtillery; }
};
```